# MySQL percentage of values in a GROUP BY query

Tags: mysql

Let's say, I have 3 tables: *appointments*, *doctors* and *departments*.

**appointments:**

```
id     status      doctor_id
----   ---------   ---------
1      approved    1
2      cancelled   4
3      approved    4
4      approved    1
5      approved    4
6      NULL        5
7      approved    2
8      NULL        5
9      approved    4
10     approved    3
11     cancelled   1
12     NULL        4
13     approved    3
14     cancelled   1
15     approved    4
16     cancelled   4
17     cancelled   2
18     NULL        4
19     cancelled   1
20     cancelled   4
```

**doctors:**

```
id     name        department_id
----   ---------   -------------
1      John        1
2      Robert      2
3      Patricia    3
4      Mary        1
5      Susan       3
```

**departments:**

```
id     name
----   ---------
1      Dermatology
2      Neurology
3      Radiology
```

---

What I need is percentage of approved appointments to total of approved and cancelled (approved / (approved + cancelled) * 100) in Dermatology department, grouped by doctors.

I used the following query, which got me closer to solution.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS appointment_count,
       doctors.name AS doctor_name,
       appointments.status AS appointment_status
FROM appointments
LEFT JOIN doctors ON appointments.doctor_id = doctors.id
LEFT JOIN departments ON doctors.department_id = departments_id
WHERE departments.id = 1
GROUP BY doctors.id,
         appointments.status
```

result:

```
count    doctor_name    appointment_status
-----    -----------    ---------
2        John           approved
3        John           cancelled
0        John           NULL
4        Mary           approved
3        Mary           cancelled
2        Mary           NULL
```

But I need the percentage of approved / (approved + cancelled) for each doctors. So the result should be:

```
approved_percentage   doctor_name
-------------------   -----------
%40                   John
%57                   Mary
```

How can I achieve such a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, the simplest way to do conditional counts and averages is simply to use the boolean expression.  This suggests:

```
SELECT d.name, count(*),
       SUM(a.status = 'approved') as approved_count,  
       AVG(a.status = 'approved') * 100 as approved_percentage
FROM doctors d INNER JOIN
     appointments a
     ON a.doctor_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group only by doctors and then use count(if()) functionality like this:

```
SELECT d.name, count(*), count(if(a.status = 'approved', 1, null)) approved_count,  
    count(if(a.status = 'approved', 1, null))/count(*) * 100 approved_percentage
    FROM doctors d
    INNER JOIN appointments a ON a.doctor_id = d.id
    GROUP BY d.name
```